# ActiveModel Serializer not being invoked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I am just trying to play around with AMS and I noticed that when I remove an attribute, the JSON response is unchanged.

```
active_model_serializers (0.9.4)
      activemodel (>= 3.2)
```

and I'm on Rails 5.

```
rails -v
Rails 5.0.0.beta3
```

This is my schema so you can see what my RentalUnits table looks like:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160303205439) do

  create_table "rental_units", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "address"
    t.integer  "rooms"
    t.integer  "bathrooms"
    t.integer  "price_cents"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  add_index "rental_units", ["user_id"], name: "index_rental_units_on_user_id"

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string   "email"
  end

end
```

This is my AMS for Rental Units. As you can see I left out address just so I can see if AMS was properly working. I expect that to cause the JSON response to not have an address node.

```
class RentalUnitSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :rooms, :bathrooms, :price, :price_per_room

  has_one :user
end
```

This is my RentalUnitsController:

```
class RentalUnitsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_rental_unit, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /rental_units
  def index
    @rental_units = RentalUnit.all

    render json: @rental_units
  end
...
```

When I visit http://localhost:3000/rental_units, this is my JSON response:

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"address": "1st address",
"rooms": 2,
"bathrooms": 2,
"price_cents": 50000,
"created_at": "2016-03-03T20:58:11.650Z",
"updated_at": "2016-03-03T20:58:11.650Z",
"user_id": 1
},
{
"id": 2,
"address": "2nd address",
"rooms": 2,
"bathrooms": 2,
"price_cents": 50000,
"created_at": "2016-03-03T20:58:11.654Z",
"updated_at": "2016-03-03T20:58:11.654Z",
"user_id": 1
},
{
```

Why is address still in there?

Comment: It actually looks like your serializer is not being used at all. Make sure you have restarted your rails server after installing the `active_model_serializers ` gem.

Comment: Is your serializer on your load_path?

Comment: Yeah I agree that my serializer isn't being used at all... why is this happening? How do I check my load_path?

Comment: @Jwan622 - what is the path of the file that defines your serializer?

Comment: @broisatse app/serializers/rental_unit_serializer.rb

Comment: @Jwan622 - Open up rails console and type "RentalUnitSerializer". If you'll got an exception modify your application.rb with `config.autoload_path << Rails.root.join('app', 'serializers')`